# disassemble object in array

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a search method in the database that brings me the following result:

[image]

As you see that inside the Object [4] comes another array containing People, Pessoas, and PessoasEnderecos and more objects that have relantionship with Pessoas.

I would like it to return only this way and not inside another array as it is happening now, it should look like this:

```
elementData=Object[10](id=144)
[0]=Pessoas(id=166)
[1]=PessoasEnderecos(id=167)
...
```

i have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/pessoas")
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Pessoas>> buscarPessoas(HttpServletRequest request) throws  Exception { 

        String idEntidadeCrypt = request.getHeader("DataBase");
        Long idEntidade = Long.parseLong(Crypto.decode(idEntidadeCrypt));

        Collection<Pessoas> pessoasBuscados = pessoasService.buscarFiltro(idEntidade);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(pessoasBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and :

```
@Repository
public interface PessoasRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoas, Integer> {

    @Query( value="select pes, pEnd, pFis, pJur "
            + "from "
            + "Pessoas pes, "
            + "PessoasEnderecos pEnd,"
            + "PessoasFisicas pFis,"
            + "PessoasJuridicas pJur"           
            + " where  "            
            + "pes.entidade.idEntidade = pEnd.entidade.idEntidade "
            + "and pes.idPessoa = pEnd.pessoa.idPessoa "
            + "and pes.entidade.idEntidade = pFis.entidade.idEntidade "
            + "and pes.idPessoa = pFis.pessoa.idPessoa "
            + "and pes.entidade.idEntidade = pJur.entidade.idEntidade "
            + "and pes.idPessoa = pJur.pessoa.idPessoa "
            + "and pes.entidade.idEntidade = :parametroId " )
    public  Collection<Pessoas>  encontrar(@Param("parametroId") Long usuarioEntidade);
```

how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<>` does not work with magic, it has an actual implementation. [`elementData`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L111) is the array where it stores its elements. As you can see (that is a link in the previous sentence), it is a private member of the class, so you do not interact with it, but you see it in a debugger because it exists.
If you want to return an array instead of a `List`, you can always use [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])) which all `List`s implement.